# Get Modelstate Information for Turlebot

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

I run ros Kinetic with gazebo 7.0. My project is a turtlebot who should drive to several objects and try to push them away after a try he should drive to the middle of the room again and drive to the next object. I tried Odometry for get information about the position of the robot but i need accurated position so i need model state.

So i think it should have a higher accuracy when i use modelstates.

I got my odometry information with following piece of code:

```
def newOdom(msg):
    global x
    global y
    global theta
    
    x = msg.pose.pose.position.x
    y = msg.pose.pose.position.y

    rot_q = msg.pose.pose.orientation
    (roll,pitch,theta) = euler_from_quaternion ([rot_q.x,rot_q.y,rot_q.z,rot_q.w])
rospy.init_node("speed_controller")
sub = rospy.Subscriber("/odom",Odometry,newOdom)
```

My question is: It is correct to make the same with the
gazebo_msgs/ModelState
I updated my code to :

```
def newModel(msg):
    global x
    global y
    global theta
    
    x = msg.pose[1].pose.position.x
    y = msg.pose.pose[1].position.y

    rot_q = msg.pose[1].pose.orientation
    (roll,pitch,theta) = euler_from_quaternion ([rot_q.x,rot_q.y,rot_q.z,rot_q.w])
rospy.init_node("speed_controller")
sub = rospy.Subscriber("/gazebo/ModelStates",ModelState,newModel)
```

I looked in publishing message and mobile base is at position 2 so it should be index 1. But all i got as x and y value is 0 even if i move the robot. Any further help?

With the subscriber note above i got no error but not the correct values.

I even tried out :

sub = rospy.Subscriber("/gazebo/model_states",ModelState,newModel)

If u use this i got following error:

```
[ERROR] [1430752035.526287969, 184.707000000]: Client [/listener] wants topic /gazebo/model_states to have datatype/md5sum [gazebo_msgs/ModelState/9330fd35f2fcd82d457e54bd54e10593], but our version has [gazebo_msgs/ModelStates/48c080191eb15c41858319b4d8a609c2]. Dropping connection.
```

This is also solved at [Modelstate error](https://answers.ros.org/question/208497/what-is-gazebo_msgsmodelstates-dependencies/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279150/get-modelstate-information-for-turlebot/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-01-09**:
Keep in mind that if you use the model state from gazebo, your code won't be usable on a real robot.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-22**:
Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the error instead of a screenshot? Text is searchable, images are not. Thanks.

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-01-22**:
posted answer solved the problem, i messed up with correct msgs, thank u for fast reply

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-22**:
Could you please still take a moment to update your question with a copy and paste of the error? This will help others to solve similar problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys , solved this problem by myself. The problem was there are to messages.

I made the mistake with :

```
sub = rospy.Subscriber("/gazebo/ModelStates",ModelState,newModel)
```

the correct one is :

```
sub = rospy.Subscriber("/gazebo/model_states",ModelStates,newModel)
```

Fixing this solved the error and i can run my program now without any problems

---

Originally posted by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) with karma: 206 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, /gazebo/model_states topic. You need to find the index of mobile_base in the models list, e.g. 6 in the amcl_demo:

`name: [bookshelf, jersey_barrier, ground_plane_0, unit_cylinder_1, Dumpster, cube_20k, mobile_base]`

and use this index to access the list of poses.  (e.g. msg.pose[6])

Odometry is not valid as global pose, as it accumulates error as the robot moves. Specially if the wheels glide, like when pushing heavy objects.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-01-21**:
so if i understand u right it should look like:

```
def newModelState(msg):
    global x
    global y
    global theta

    x = msg.pose[6].pose.position.x
    y = msg.pose[6].pose.position.y

    rot_q = msg.pose[6].pose.orientation
```

?

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-01-21**:
Can u tell me how the subscriber should look like? I am relative new with coding in ros ...

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2018-01-21**:
The ROS tutorials cover perfectly the issue:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-01-22**:
updated question thank u for ur help got it now!